# Getting count of entries for a sub-model with date filtering in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filtering, inner-join, activemodel, counter-cache

I want to get count of objects for a sub-model in Rails with date filtering.

### Let's explain in detail:

Assume that I have two models.

- Post
- Comment

Also the `Comment` model belongs to `Post` model

I want to get comments count for each post by date range. For example; I want to get only today's counts.

Does anyone have an idea that how can I do it without many DB queries? Is it possible with counter cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One single query

```
date_start = params[:date_from].to_date.beginnig_of_day
date_end = params[:date_end].to_date.end_of_day

Post.includes(:comments)
      .where(comments: {created_at: date_start..date_end})
      .group(:id)
      .count
```